# Can't find mistake in my code, I am validating user is logined and has token stored in localstorage, but can;t get back token from localstorage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

//Home page in reactJs

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import landingpic from '../assets/images/landingpage.jpg';


let my_token;
const Home = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
  const callHomePage = async() => {
  my_token = window.localStorage.getItem(my_token);
  console.log(my_token);
  const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/getdata',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer" + my_token,
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({my_token})
  });
    const res = data.json();
    setUserName(res.name);
    console.log(res.name);
    if(!res.status===200 || !res){
      const error = new Error(res.error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    callHomePage();
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className='main_content'>


        {/* left side content */}
        <div className='main_content_left'>
          <p>Online Learning</p>
          <h1>Learn EveryDay</h1>
          <p>Hey {userName} Great way to learn is by playing games.<br/>Come everyday and play these quiz challanges<br/>and learn with fun</p>
          <button>Start Game</button>
        </div>


        {/* right side content */}
        <div className='main_content_right'>
          <img src={landingpic} alt="quiztime" className='quizimage' />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

// getdata route

```
router.post('/getdata',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

///authenticate middleware

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require('../model/userSchema');

const authenticate = async(req,res,next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    console.log(`verified token is ${token}`);
    if(token == null){
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    const rootUser = await User.findOne({_id:verifyToken,"tokens.token":token});

    if(!rootUser) {throw new Error('User not found')};

    req.token=token;
    req.rootUser=rootUser;
    req.userID=rootUser._id;
    next();
}

module.exports = authenticate;
```

/// login.js frontend file

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  const [user,setUser] = useState({email:"",password:""});
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  let name;
  let value;
  const handleInputs = (e) =>{
    name=e.target.name;
    value=e.target.value;

    setUser({...user,[name]:value});
  }


  const postdata = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const{email,password} = user;

    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/signin',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        email,password
      })
    });

    const res = await data.json();
    if(res.status===422 || !res){
      window.alert("Login failed");
    }
    else{
      window.alert("Login Successful");
      window.localStorage.setItem("my_token",res.my_token);
      navigate('/');
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='outer_form_div'>
        <div className='inner_form_div' style={{height: "60vh"}}>
          <div className='form_heading_div'>
            <h1>Log In</h1>
            <p>Doesn't have an account? <a href='/signup'>Sign Up</a></p>
          </div>
          <div className='form_div'>
            <form method='POST'>
              <label>Email</label><br/>
              <input type="email" name="email" value={user.email} onChange={handleInputs} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your email"/><br/><br/>
              <label>Password</label><br/>
              <input type="password" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={handleInputs} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your password"/><br/><br/>
              
              <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={postdata} className='submitbtn'/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

In my this code I am trying to validate that if user is authorized then display its name on home page, the user if has jwt token stored in localStorage it send token through auth. headers to server on route /getdata. The problem is that the token when generated gets stored in localStorage but after when user is redirected to home page the token is sadi to be null. I can't figure out the mistake, please anyone help me with my mistake. It would be a great help.

Comment: You attempt to get the token w/ an undefined variable as the local storage item name. It’s also not clear how the token gets put into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a .getItem from local storage using the variable you want to store the value of the result as the key.

Try doing something like this instead.

```
my_token = window.localStorage.getItem("<your storage key>");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: like if my stored token is my_token should i write like this   
```
my_token = window.localStorage.getItem("my_token");
```

??

Comment: @rahultiwari all items in local storage are stored as key/value pairs. You look up your token using the accompanying key. I don't see in your code where you set your local storage, but for example, if you did localStorage.setItem("MyTokenKey", "SomeMagicTokenValue123"). then you would GET that token from local storage by doing myToken = localStorage.getItem("MyTokenKey"). The result would be that the variable myToken will now contain the value "SomeMagicTokenValue123"

Comment: I have done the same way as your are saying, please again check the question I have now  added the code where I am setting localStorage, it's in my login file in reactjs

Comment: Just update your getItem logic to this: my_token = window.localStorage.getItem("my_token"); and put a space between "Bearer" and your token in the "Authentication" header. 'Authorization': "Bearer " + my_token,